# ContactList not working

Tags: java, android

please can someone assist this is a really stupid question but here goes..

I am trying to get the Retrieving a List of Contacts example 
to work on https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html in the try it out section.

When I attempt to run/debug the project the only option I get is edit the configuration and therafter I click run and nothing happens.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: where your trying ?

Comment: sorry in android studio

Comment: emulator or real device ? if emulator der is no contacts so its expected result.

Comment: real device. I see there are no gradle scripts

Comment: does your device has contacts

Comment: yes it does quite a bit

Comment: It would be easier if you include a picture for us to know how the actual error look like.

Comment: on which device are you working or test your code?

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that there are no gradle scripts in the file. I will include a screenshot now.

Comment: I am testing the file on the same device where I do all other app testing. I have in the meanwhile tested another project in android studio on the device and it works.